# Javascript Loop for same commands

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to loop this instead of 6 seperate versions of this. It's obviously redundant code. I would have no issues doing this in PHP.

I would like to keep this purely JS.

```
    function p1Name() {
    document.getElementById('p1_name_1').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById('p1_name_2').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById('p1_name_3').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById('p1_name_4').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById('p1_name_5').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById('p1_name_6').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById('p1_name_7').innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

This same function gets repeated 6 times.
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6

Comment: Yes, you really should use a loop. Please show us what you tried.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use sequential ids, rather put a `class` on all of those elements and get them as a collection from the `document`

Comment: I tried using a class before but i couldn't get getElementsByClassName('blah') to work correctly. I also tried various methods trying to loop them. I ended up deleting them all in frustration :-(

Comment: That's nothing we can help you with, you need to post your attempts so that we can find out what went wrong

Comment: @Quinton You might have seen me give an answer to this question which I have now (temporarily) deleted. On a second thought I realized that I shouldn't have answered this question in its current form to begin with. If you included specific attempts and the issues with those (as Bergi has already asked you to do) I'd gladly undelete my answer again.

Comment: @keiwan after some slight adjustments your answer worked very well. I have an additional comment to ask about it.

Comment: @bergi This is my first time posting to stackoverflow. In the future I will save previous attempts.

Comment: @Quinton I've undeleted it so you can ask your question. I still encourage you to edit your question to include your attempts. Even if you don't have code any more you could still include your train of thoughts (e.g. how you would have tackled this problem in PHP and what is causing you troubles when trying to "translate" that solution into JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off the answer by Keiwan... the function would still need to be called several times... you can access object properties such as scorecard.p1 as scorecard["p1"]. So, to call it just once.

```
function pName(px) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    document.getElementById(px + '_name_' + i).innerHTML = (scorecard[px][scorecard[px].selectedIndex].text);
  }
}
```

That's provided that px is fed in as a string.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you @keiwan and rjerue. You answered my questions before I could even ask it. I needed to replace the "p1" reference with [px].

Answer (score 1):

You just have to construct the names of your elements (`p(x)_name_(i)`). Since you want to call the function 6 times (for `p1...p6`) you should pass that as an argument (`px`) to the function:

```
function pName(px) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        document.getElementById(px + '_name_' + i).innerHTML = (scorecard.p1[scorecard.p1.selectedIndex].text);
    }
}
```

You would then call this function for each `p1...p6` (which depending on your circumstances you'll probably also going to want to do in a loop). I'm going to leave that one to you since you can use the same concept as the one in the function above.